# How do i rotate an object in unity at a set of amount time stop it and then again

Tags: unityscript

I'm not good at coding so please help me with my problem.

What i mean with: How do i rotate an object in unity at a set of amount time stop it and then again

is how can i rotate an object at a set of amount time then stop it at a set of amount time then stop it etc.

VideoNations

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be like this:

```
// control the timing of rotating here
var rotate=true;
function Start () {
    // rotate an object for 2 seconds
    rotate=true;
    yield WaitForSeconds(2f);

    // stop it for a second
    rotate=false;
    yield WaitForSeconds(1f);

    // rotate again
    rotate=true;
}

// rotate here
function Update() {
    if(rotate)
        transform.eulerAngles+=Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime*90, 0);
}
```

If you want the rotation enabling-disabling to loop, wrap the contents of `Start` in a `while(true) {...}`.